# Preventing Color Bleed when using Graphics.Drawstring()?

Tags: colors, drawstring

How do I prevent colors form bleeding into one another when using the vb .net Graphics.Drawstring method. This Occurs with colors that really shouldnt be used together eg green/orange and black and red.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have antialiasing enabled. Have you tried to disable that?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by generating png's instead of jpegs the quality ended up being a lot better